# Java Primefaces how to work with elements placed in dataTable column header

Tags: java, primefaces

When "selectOneMenu" is placed in the "dataTable" column header it:
1) triggers row sorting everytime it is opened or after the button next to it is clicked and "selectOneMenu" is opened (it shouldn't be like that);
2) fails to assign value to the backing bean.
How can "selectOneMenu" be attached to the column header so that these problems wouldn't occur?

*.xhtml code with dataTable which causes 1) and 2) problems:

```
<h:form id="someForm0">
    <p:dataTable id="sdt" var="variable" value="#{otherBean.tableModel}" rows="10">
            <p:column sortBy="#{variable.name}" filterBy="#{variable.name}"  filterMatchMode="contains" >
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Name"/>
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="1">
                            <p:selectOneMenu id="abc" value="#{userBean.someChars}">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="select" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="AAA" itemValue="AAA" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="BBB" itemValue="BBB" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="CCC" itemValue="CCC" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                        <h:commandButton id="btn" value="Submit" type="submit" action="#{userBean.submitChars}"/>
                        </h:panelGrid>
                </f:facet>  
                <h:outputText value="#{variable.name}"/>  
            </p:column>  
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Backing bean code:

```
@ManagedBean
public class UserBean
{
    private String someChars;

    public String getSomeChars()
    {
        return someChars;
    }

    public void setSomeChars(String someChars)
    {
        this.someChars = someChars;
    }

    public String submitChars()
    {
       if(getSomeChars() != null)
       {
           System.out.println("Selected chars are: " + getSomeChars());
       }
       else
       {
            System.out.println("Selected chars are equal to null!");
       }
       return null;
    }
}
```

Here is fragment of the previously mentioned *.xhtml code, and selectOneMenu works just great when placed into the basic form:

```
<h:form id="someForm">
    <p:selectOneMenu id="abc" value="#{userBean.someChars}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="select" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="AAA" itemValue="AAA" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="BBB" itemValue="BBB" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="CCC" itemValue="CCC" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
    <h:commandButton id="btn" value="Submit" type="submit" action="#{userBean.submitChars}"/>
</h:form>
```

I think the last resort would be adding elements from the dataTable column header to the dataTable header:

```
<h:form id="someForm1">
    <p:dataTable id="sdt" var="variable" value="#{otherBean.tableModel}" rows="10">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="1">
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="abc" value="#{userBean.someChars}">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="select" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="AAA" itemValue="AAA" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="BBB" itemValue="BBB" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="CCC" itemValue="CCC" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                    <h:commandButton id="btn" value="Submit" type="submit" action="#{userBean.submitChars}"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </f:facet>
            <p:column sortBy="#{variable.name}" filterBy="#{variable.name}"  filterMatchMode="contains" >
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Name"/>
                </f:facet>  
                <h:outputText value="#{variable.name}"/>  
            </p:column>  
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as below :

```
<h:form id="someForm0">
    <p:dataTable id="sdt" ...>
        <p:column headerText="header">
                <p:selectOneMenu id="abc" value="#{userBean.someChars}">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="select" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="AAA" itemValue="AAA" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="BBB" itemValue="BBB" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="CCC" itemValue="CCC" />
                    <p:ajax event="valueChange" update=":someForm0:sdt"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>  
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
    <h:commandButton ....>
</h:form>
```

UserBean.java

```
private String someChars;

public String getSomeChars() {
    return someChars;
}

public void setSomeChars(Stirng someChars) {
    this.someChars = someChars;
}
```

Comment: CycDemo, to be precise ajax event should be written something like this:

    <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{userBean.onSelectOneMenuChange}" onchange="submit()"/>

and code in bean:
 public void onSelectOneMenuChange(AjaxBehaviorEvent event)
 {
  System.out.println("Trying to change something");
 }

Unfortunatelly this doesn't solve neither 1) nor 2) problem.